# Unable to install Rock Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I use ubuntu as my dev machine. On Localhost. I have installed apache

I followed the instructions given here:

http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo#Quick_Install

But I am not able to do access the site at localhost/rockmongo/index.php

My apache has the default config I think. This is the config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I can provide additional details.

Comment: what error you are getting ? have you installed mongodb ?

Comment: Yeah. I have installed mongodb. I get a 404 error

Comment: where you have install rockmongo ? and what is URL ?

Comment: On localhost, I have installed apache

Comment: Is rockmongo in a directory in your webroot called rockmongo? Or is the directory called something else. A 404 error occurs because it cannot find that directory/file in your webroot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your virtual host file is messed up. This is what I have as my virtual host and it works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin scott@iosdeveloperforums.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Sites/rockmongo/"
    ServerName local.rockmongo.com
    ServerAlias www.local.rockmongo.com
    ErrorLog "logs/local.rockmongo.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/local.rockmongo.com-access_log" common

<Directory "/var/www/Sites/rockmongo">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```